# Unable to reset proxy in Eclipse MARS

Tags: eclipse, proxy

I installed CDT on top of Eclipse MARS IDE for JAVA developers on Fedora 22. After a reboot, I am unable to reset proxy in Eclipse. When I click on *Network Connections* I get an error message *The currently displayed page contains invalid values*.

[After the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UmfA.png)

The Active provider has to be set to 'Manual', but the drop down list is now missing.
Eclipse starts with the following messages:

> org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The
>   org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the
>   state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location
>   is initialized. org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config
>   file:
>   /root/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.6.2.20150902-0002.xml
>   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [bundleresource://472.fwk12572413:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [bundleresource://472.fwk12572413:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
>   org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback

There are no messages even after the error is encountered. Which configuration file should I change to reset proxy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately this is known issue with the latest eclipse mars version.
Description could be found here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479075

Workaround: 
create file "org.eclipse.core.net.prefs" under ${eclipse.install.dir}/configuration/.settings with content:

```
nonProxiedHosts=localhost
```

Comment: Adding the line to an already exiting file in that location fixed the issue for me too.

Comment: That has not worked for me.

$ uname -a
Darwin localhost 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Tue Sep  1 21:23:09 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.50.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: The fix needed a restart after the change - then worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you move your install directory ?
Because this exact same problem happend to me after I (brutally) moved the Eclipse install directories.

A re-install cleared the problem.

Comment: I did not move the install directory. I simply rebooted the system. I have tried re-installing Eclipse. This happens every time I reboot the system after installation. Could this have something to do with special characters in proxy password?